# How does absorbing radio waves create an alternating current in a conductor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, waves

I was reading this in my textbook and I don’t understand how absorbing radio waves creates an alternating current in the conductor. Please refrain to simple explanations, I am just a tenth grader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A radio wave is a jiggling of the electromagnetic field, just like any electromagnetic wave. Electrons in a conductor, such as an aerial, respond to the electromagnetic field because they are charged. Because they are free to flow throughout the conductor, they tend to move with the field so to speak - just like a cork in a swimming pool.

This swash of electrons back and forth can be detected as an "alternating current".

---

Credit for the analogy of a cork on a swimming pool is from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WLiIGOCrHqQ).